# How do you smartly apply an array to a chart?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2012, charts

In my program, I've got a few arrays that I'd like to apply to a few charts in Visual Studios. These arrays will always be the same size (2,2 for the vast majority). The array's first "column" will always hold the labels of the columns in my chart, and the array's second "column" will always hold the values for those labels. I've been looking around, and using the Charts object built into visual studios doesn't have a "chart.column" property. Additionally, every solution I look up seems overly complicated. This should be a pretty simple thing, shouldn't it?

Let's say my chart's name is "chtEvaluations", and my array is called "myArr". I was originally thinking I could do something as simple as

```
    chtEvaluations.columns(0).label = myArr[0,0]
    chtEvaluations.columns(0).value = Convert.ToInt32(myArr[0,1])
```

Is it really more difficult than this? I haven't been able to find any solutions anywhere near this.